# How to get group of key events in OfferKeyEventL function of Container class in Symbian S60

Tags: symbian, s60

I am using Carbide.C++ 2.3 and S60 3rd FP2 SDK

In Container's OfferKeyEventL function I am receiving all the key events but how can I identify key map/key group?

I mean to ask how to identify is it Alpha key event or Numeric Key event or special key event??

Please guide me...

Answer (score 0):

You can use iCode and iScanCode members of TKeyEvent for that.

```
/** The character code generated for an EEventKey, or 0 for a down or up event.
Key codes for special keys are defined in TKeyCode. */
TUint iCode;

/** The scan code of the key that caused the event.
Standard scan codes are defined in TStdScanCode. */
TInt iScanCode;
```

Comment: This I know. I want to know the group of the key.